# Is it Possible to Display Editable Text In A Shell Via The Standard C++ IOStream?

Tags: c++, shell, console, text-editor, iostream

Is it possible to display **interactive** and **editable** text in a console via a standard C++ `iostream`?

In other words, would it be possible to have basic Vim-esque text editing abilities using only the standard C++ `iostream` within a shell?

For example, suppose a simple string `exampleText` containing the text "Example text." was displayed in a shell window using the code:

```
std::string exampleText = "Example text.";
std::string editedText;
std::cout << exampleText;
```

would it be possible to edit the string stored in `exampleText` while it is displayed in a shell and then save the edited version of that string into `editedText`?

I have doubts about this being possible, but if anyone could help to clarify whether or not this would be possible I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What OS are you using?  It matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it is possible. Just output the correct terminal escapes. For each escape make sure you cover for all the popular terminals.

Or save yourself the trouble and use readline or ncurses.

Comment: I tried using \r and \b but neither of those seemed to have work. Is their a different escape sequence that I should be using? My code:    #include <iostream>

int main() {
 std::cout << "Test." << "\b";
 return 0;
}